# matplotlib histograms and labels

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting a histogram with two sets of data and want to include a key. I have found an example that uses the label command, but when I use this it doesn't work. The histogram appears correctly, but there is no key. My code is.

```
H1 = <some data>
S1 = <some other data>

hist([H1,S1], bins=25, range=(10,30), align=('mid'), color=['green', 'orange'], label=['Actual H band', 'Actual IRAC2 band'])
title("Actual observed magnitudes of sources in H and IRAC2")
xlabel("Magnitude")
ylabel("Frequency")

show()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to include a legend call:

```
H1 = <some data>
S1 = <some other data>

hist([H1,S1], bins=25, range=(10,30), align=('mid'), color=['green', 'orange'], label=['Actual H band', 'Actual IRAC2 band'])
title("Actual observed magnitudes of sources in H and IRAC2")
xlabel("Magnitude")
ylabel("Frequency")
legend()

show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that in the example :)